# Merging accounts with chatter feeds and attachments

Tags: merge

According to [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_merge_considerations.htm&type=0):

> When duplicate records are related to items such as campaigns or
>   activities, Salesforce relates the items to the merged record, with
>   some exceptions. Chatter feeds are retained from the master record
>   only. Attachments in Chatter feeds are retained in Salesforce but
>   aren’t associated with the merged record. To associate the dropped
>   files with the merged record, find them in Files home (in Lightning
>   Experience) or the Files tab (in Salesforce Classic). Then add them to
>   the Files related list on the merged record.

So, my question is, what's the best way to merge accounts including their attachments and chatter feeds? I know Apex is one option, but I was wondering if there is any other option that doesn't involve developing a Batch process.

Thanks!